# SQL Server : Deadlocks during token issuing stored procedure in multi-process scenario

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

We have a set of items in a table , and the worker children invokes a `StoredProc(get_next_item)` to get the next item to be worked upon.

The stored procedure attaches a `token` to an Item at each invocation, and returns back the item in the below order

- First Items marked as 'P1'
- And then rest of them

Sample data:

```
item   priority token
--------------------------
item1   P1      NULL
item2   NULL    NULL
item3   P1      NULL
item4   NULL    NULL
item5   P1      NULL
item6   NULL    NULL
item7   NULL    NULL
```

Stored procedure "get_next_item":

```
Declare @token int,
        @item varchar(50),
        @prty varchar(50)

EXEC get_token 'token_key',@token out

BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
    SET ROWCOUNT 1

    -- FIRST TRY P1 ITEMS (U1)
    UPDATE Item_audit 
    SET token = @token
    WHERE priority = 'P1' AND token IS NULL

    SELECT @rows = @@ROWCOUNT

    -- IF no more P1 then rest of the items (U2)
    IF 0 = @rows
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Item_audit 
        SET token = @token
        WHERE token IS NULL

        SELECT @rows = @@ROWCOUNT
    END

    IF @rows <> 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @item = item , @prty = priority
        FROM Item_audit 
        WHERE token = @token
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        ROLLBACK

    SET @err_msg = 'Exception '

    GOTO ERROR
END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
    COMMIT
```

**Issues**:

Deadlocks are seen at update statements (U1 & U2) when multiple unix processes invoke the `StoredProc(get_next_item)`, why?

Answer (score 0):

I would replace all of these update and selecting from table multiple times with a single update along with output clause query.

Also move your `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN` inside the `TRY BLOCK` why leave the transaction hanging for so long only to be rolled back if something went wrong in the try block? doesn't make sense.

Anyway I would rewrite the whole thing something like....

```
Declare @token int
       ,@item varchar(50)
       ,@prty varchar(50)

EXEC get_token 'token_key',@token out

BEGIN TRY

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    Declare @L TABLE (item VARCHAR(50),  [priority] VARCHAR(50),  token INT);

    WITH X AS (
                Select TOP 1 * 
                from Item_audit
                WHERE ([priority] = 'P1' AND token IS NULL)
                    OR (token IS NULL)
                ORDER BY [priority] desc
    )
    UPDATE X 
        SET token = @token
    OUTPUT inserted.token , inserted.[priority] , inserted.item 
    INTO @L (token , [priority], item)


    Select @item = item 
         , @prty = [priority] 
         , @token = token 
    FROM @L 

 COMMIT TRANSACTION;    
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    SET @err_msg = 'Exception '

END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks Ali , wondering what could be the reason for deadlocks ?

Comment: You have too many unnecessaryupdate statements and selects, reduing the amount of updates and selects will definitely help.

Comment: **Update :** The deadlocks seem to go away when the queries were made more specific like `U1 : WHERE ISNULL(priority,'%^@^%') = 'P1' AND token IS NULL` and `U2 : WHERE ISNULL(priority,'%^@^%') <> 'P1' AND token IS NULL`

Comment: @Ali : Wondering how ISNULL could make a difference ?